# How to make filters in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to deal with MassTransit, I have a number of servers with StableDefussion and they accept tasks for generating images in the queue

But the fact is that different servers have a different set of models and I would not want to create a lot of queues for each model

How can my GPU servers filter tasks from the queue and take into work only those that they can perform?

My PublisherServer

```
internal class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(ServerConfig.Host), h => {
                h.Username(ServerConfig.Username);
                h.Password(ServerConfig.Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("calculation_results_queue", e => {
                e.Consumer(() => new ResultConsumer());
            });
        });
        await busControl.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Publisher is running...");


        await busControl.Publish<CalculationTask>(new {
            TaskId = NewId.NextGuid().ToString(),
            Data = "Important data for calculation"
        }, context => {
            context.Headers.Set("model", "model_comic");
        });


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey());
        await busControl.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

My GPU worker

```
internal class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(ServerConfig.Host), h => {
                h.Username(ServerConfig.Username);
                h.Password(ServerConfig.Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("calculation_task_queue", e => {
                e.Bind("headers_exchange", x => {
                    x.ExchangeType = "headers";
                    x.SetExchangeArgument("x-match", "any");
                    x.SetExchangeArgument("model", "model_real");
                    x.SetExchangeArgument("model", "model_anime");
                });

                e.Consumer(() => new CalculationTaskConsumer());
            });
        });

        await busControl.StartAsync();


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey());
        await busControl.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

My worker wasn't supposed to receive messages, but he does it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("calculation_task_queue", e => {

    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
    
    e.Bind("headers_exchange", x => {
        x.ExchangeType = "headers";
        x.SetExchangeArgument("x-match", "any");
        x.SetExchangeArgument("model", "model_real");
        x.SetExchangeArgument("model", "model_anime");
    });

    e.Consumer(() => new CalculationTaskConsumer());
});
```

The default topology configuration is likely the reason, but you could have figured that out by looking at the RabbitMQ management console and seeing the additional binding.

Comment: During this time, I studied MassTransit a little more and got even more confused.

exchange is used to automatically determine which queue a published message will be sent to.

But I want one queue for all models, which means that all types of messages will be sent to calculation_task_queue and all workers will take these messages for themselves even if they do not fit them.

Do I understand correctly that Bind on the worker side will never work as a filter? Does he just create an exchange on the server?

Comment: In addition for proper operation, you need to run the PublisherServer and the worker so that all the necessary settings are created. I can't automatically create everything I need when I first launch PublisherServer?

I began to doubt that rabbitmq is generally able to filter messages based on a single queue distributing tasks to the right workers